# Run a program background even close the ssh connection

Tags: bash, ssh

I connected a machine via ssh and ran a programme. It took too long to run the programme and I have to turn off my local machine. How can I run the programme background even close the ssh connection?

I am running the code but if I rerun the code, it took a lot of the time, if I close the ssh, the program will be closed, so there are there any method to make the running program still running background even I close the ssh connection.

Answer (score 0):

There are various options you have to achieve this.

- append `&` to the command you run.
- run `nohup command &` and then press enter
- Use [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/)

Comment: I am running the code but if I rerun the code, it took a lot of time, if I close the ssh, the program will be closed, so are there any methods to make the running program run background even I close the ssh connection.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add a couple more tools to the list above

- [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen)
- [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki)

tmux is the more modern one and you can find numerous config examples on GitHub.